# Tables for JdbcTaskExecutionDao

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using `@EnableTask` with `JdbcTaskExecutionDao` and I can't find SQLs to create tables in my database (SQL Server). Where I can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it from Spring Cloud github: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/cloud/task/schema-h2.sql

Answer (score 0):

If your target database is MS SQL Server, while starting the Spring Cloud Task application, if you supply the driver and datasource credentials, the application will automatically bootstrap with SQL Server specific schema. You don't have to create them manually - the framework will build it for you.